# Every npm command throwing errors

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I'm playing around with a test Laravel app and I'm trying to run "npm run watch" but it just throws errors. Even with "npm install", it does the same thing. I'm on a Mac by the way. I just can't get anything to work and I have no idea why. If I've missed some information that you need, please tell me. Thanks in advance!

[npm run watch](https://hastebin.com/umekikokov.js) - log file

[npm install](https://hastebin.com/ejocovugun.sql) - error from terminal (log file was like 10k lines)

Comment: There are many permission errors in there, is your directory writable? It could be the square brackets in the path?

Comment: it looks like you have some permission problem in this folder, please check if your current user has the permission to write in this folder, maybe also check if nodejs/npm is properly installed, if they have proper permission.

Comment: @Flimzy - There are no screenshots. There are just hastebin links to keep the question clean.

Comment: @bearzk - I went to get info on the node_modules folder and changed everything to read & write, but this is still happening. I've seen some sort of "chmod" command but I don't know much about it. Would I use it here?

Comment: @Techmo on a mac you can use `ls -l . ` to check the current folder's permission/owernship, if you see, say Techmo is your user name, a lot Techmo staff after file/folder names, you are fine. you can try `chown -R .` in this project folder to make sure everything within (recursively) are owned by current user.

Comment: @Techmo: Oh, indeed. The syntax highlighting fooled me. In any case, please put the relevant text in the question directly.

Comment: @bearzk I did `ls -l` and it appears that "root" owns all the files. I tried `chown -R` but it just kept coming up with the usage of `chown`.

Comment: @Techmo then that should be it, all root is not right, maybe you have cloned/created this project with `sudo`? but for now try it with `sudo` then, `sudo chown -R .` should work. if npm or node only runs smoothly with `sudo`, there's something wrong with your node installation, read about environemtn variables `NODE_PATH` and `NPM_PACKAGES`.

Comment: @bearzk everything runs smoothly now after the ownership change. Thanks so much for your help! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got everything working now. I just needed to change ownership of the node_module files. <3

Answer (score 1):

You have to try to uninstall the node.js and again install the nodejs(8.00.4 LTS version. Link("https://nodejs.org/en/download/")). Then to checking the node.js running properly or not go to the terminal and type command 'node -v' it shows the node.js installed version. Then try to implement the npm commands.